# Windows Phone ListView Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am trying to create a ListView of items and to be able to delete them. Here is my code. I can't get the list of items to display. I didn't find a simple example of binding ListViews so i can understand the exact concept. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong ?

PS. myListOfItems is a list with strings. The project is WP 8.1 WinRT.

```
    public class MedClass
    {
        public string medName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MedClassRoot
    {
        public List<MedClass> medNames { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed partial class MedSavedPage : Page
    {
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MedClassRoot root = new MedClassRoot();
            root.medNames = new List<MedClass>();

            foreach (var element in myListOfItems)
            {
                root.medNames.Add(new MedClass {medName = element});
            }

            MedSaved_ListView.DataContext = root;
            //MedSaved_ListView.ItemsSource = root;
        }

    <ListView DataContext="{Binding root}"
              x:Name="MedSaved_ListView" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="507" 
              Margin="10,73,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="380" Tapped="MedSaved_ListView_Tapped">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="30">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding medName}" FontSize="16"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the quickest way to get it to work:

- Remove the DataContext part from the ListView for now.
- Simply set the ItemsSource to the list of your items (comment the part where you do MedSaved_ListView.DataContext = root, and uncomment and alter the next line)

  ```
  MedSaved_ListView.ItemsSource = root.medNames;
  ```

Explanation - the ListView ItemsSource is collection used to generate the content of the ItemsControl. You need to set it to some kind of IEnumerable. Your medNames is of type List which implements IEnumerable so you need to set the ItemsSource to it.

Comment: And when i will want to remove an element from the ListView, i remove the element from medNames, but how do i refresh the ListView so it does not show that element ?

Comment: @Macaret in this case, your setup is a bit wrong. You need to use ObservableCollection as it's capable of notifying the UI when there's a collection change event (when you remove an item, for example). Please read some of the many tutorials on topics: databinding, ObservableCollection, ListBox or ListView, perhaps even MVVM, such as: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quick_thoughts/archive/2014/06/10/data-binding-part-3-observable-collection.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for the link you gave me. I implemented the ObservableCollection and succeded in displaying my list and also deleting an item.

Comment: @Macaret You are welcome. If it answers your question, please mark it as "answer" so that others can benefit from it, too.