# Windows Phone - News block

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a block that contain news that i'd like to implement in a scroll viewer.
The block should look like this :

- Picture in the top-right resolution (with a resolution : 50*50 );
- Text wrapped along with the picture ;

  ```
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="20,0,20,0">
      <StackPanel>
          <Button Width="Auto" Height="150">
              /*Text and picture here like described before*/
          </Button>
          <Button Width="Auto" Height="150">
              /*Text and picture here like described before*/
          </Button>
      </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
  ```

PS : I'd like to design it only , not trying to make a functional app.

Comment: Got a visual example?

Comment: Something like the android app newsstand :
http://www.androidos.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/google-newsstand.png
Where the news blocks are buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Grid` with `ColumnDefinitions` inside your `Button`, for example:

```
 <Button Width="Auto"
                    Height="50"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid Height="50">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="Sample text - lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               Margin="12"/>

                    <Image Grid.Column="1"
                           Source="SampleImageSourceHere"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Width="50" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>
```

Note: It's only sample, I didn't test it but you can try to adjust your view. Hope it helps.

Futhermore I recommend to use a ListView if you'll add a big amount of items (Buttons) into your list. ListView supports virtualizaton and avoids memory problems.

If you have source collection of items, you can just create `ListView` with item template and set `ItemsSource`. I found thread about it here: [Windows Phone ListView Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646058/windows-phone-listview-binding)